# From IntelliJ changelist I want to see the list of updated files without their tree structure

Tags: intellij-idea, changelist

The following image is my changelist as I see it.

[image: CHANGELIST SCREEN IMG]

I would like to see only a list of all modified files (like the 'application.yml') but not the folders/packages which contains them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping can be configured in Commit toolwindow.

If you disable grouping, then you will achieve the desired view.

[image]